# New SE site for Programming Language Design

Tags: discussion, stackexchange

As Proof Assistants is one of the newest SE sites, many of you might remember the process that's in place for getting a new site approved, and many of you might remember how exciting it is to be one of the first users of a brand new SE site.

After Proof Assistants and Substrate/Polkadot went live on the same day about a year ago, the only two sites that have gone live were Bioacoustics and Solana, both which I didn't think overlapped enough with Proof Assistants to notify the community here.

However the [Programming Language Design](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/127456/programming-language-design-and-implementation?referrer=NjE4NDEyZTRhYWI0MTA0NGZiMTI5MDZlZDhhMDk1MjE2OGM5Y2I2OGExYTQwNTFiNzAwZjc5OGEzZmE3OTQyOJyrV3dVI5xVz9VEVF0LfiP1mv6kDbcQB8iTVOM2FU-f0) proposal, which has begun with a ***very healthy start*** is one that I think a lot of people here might find interesting.

Many of you might remember that during the approval process, I advertised Proof Assistants on [here on Mathematics.Meta](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/34489/202425), [here on MathOverflow.Meta](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/5219/66334), [here on Computer Science Meta](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1790/61663), [here on CS Theory Meta](https://cstheory.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3077/35155) and [here on Matter Modeling Meta](https://mattermodeling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/321/5).

If you are excited about the launch of a new site, or curious to experience contributing to a brand new site, or otherwise have interest in participating in a new site about programming language design, I encourage you to [visit the proposal for Programming Language Design SE](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/127456/programming-language-design-and-implementation?referrer=NjE4NDEyZTRhYWI0MTA0NGZiMTI5MDZlZDhhMDk1MjE2OGM5Y2I2OGExYTQwNTFiNzAwZjc5OGEzZmE3OTQyOJyrV3dVI5xVz9VEVF0LfiP1mv6kDbcQB8iTVOM2FU-f0) and to click on "commit"!  If you haven't ever done this before, make sure to click on "sign up" instead of "log in", but you won't have to do much more because Area51 will sign you up based on your existing SE credentials.

Often people hesitate to click "commit" because it asks you to promise that you'll post at least 10 questions or answers on the new site, but don't worry about that because most people that click "commit" do not fulfill that commitment, and there's no negative consequences for not following through with your commitment. However if you do follow through with your commitment you do get rewarded for that.